# Custom Assembly Attribute Issue Across Assemblies

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, custom-attributes

I have the following code in assembly A:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly)]
public class AssemblyCategoryAttribute : Attribute {
    public string Category { get; set; }

    public AssemblyCategoryAttribute(string category) {
        Category = category;
    }
}
```

Assembly B references assembly A and has this attribute applied. Finally assembly C also references assembly A and has the following code:

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("..."); // Get assembly B
var description = assembly.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<AssemblyDescriptionAttribute>().SingleOrDefault();
var category = assembly.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<AssemblyCategoryAttribute>().SingleOrDefault();
```

However it gets the description fine but the category returns null. I'd appreciate it if someone could help me solve this. Thanks

**Edit**

As requested in the comments, here's my AssemblyInfo.cs file in assembly B:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using AssemblyANameSpace;

[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Name")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCategory("Core")]

...
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you assign the attributes?

Comment: @AlexMendez I've updated the question with the AssemblyInfo.cs file in assembly B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following:

1. I created AssemblyA, and AssebmlyB, and WindowsFormApplication1
2. I added reference of AssemblyA which contained
   AssemblyCategoryAttribute to AssemblyB and  to
   WindowsFormApplication1
3. I added AssemblyCategory attribute to AssemblyB

This seem to work for me:

```
string assemblyFile = @"D:\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\ClassLibrary1\bin\x64\Debug\AssemblyB.dll";
byte[] assemblyBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(assemblyFile);

var assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyBytes); // Get assembly B 
var description = assembly.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<AssemblyDescriptionAttribute>().SingleOrDefault(); 
var category = assembly.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<AssemblyCategoryAttribute>().SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to do the trick. Not quite sure why that would be any different mind.